# Is date in database between today and last week

Tags: php, mysql, sql, time

I have been trying to find out how to write a SQL query to get the number of users that have registered in the system during the last week. This is my query right now:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM profile WHERE registration_date BETWEEN $week_ago AND $current_date
```

It renders an error. The php variables used are defined here:

```
$week_ago = date('Y m d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 week'));
$current_date = date('Y m d H:i:s', time());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in pure SQL

```
SELECT count(id) 
FROM profile 
WHERE registration_date BETWEEN now() -  interval 7 day 
                            AND now()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your php, but you can do this in sql:

```
SELECT count(id) 
FROM profile 
WHERE registration_date 
BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
  AND NOW()
```

Answer (score 1):

in SQL it was as below

```
SELECT count(id) 
FROM profile 
WHERE registration_date BETWEEN (Cast(GetDate() as date)-7)
                            AND Cast(GetDate() as date)
```

Or u try this one also

```
SELECT count(id) 
FROM profile 
WHERE registration_date >= (Cast(GetDate() as date)-7)
                            AND registration_date <= Cast(GetDate() as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes around $week_ago and $current_date in you SQL statement..

```
SELECT count(id) FROM profile WHERE registration_date BETWEEN '$week_ago' AND '$current_date'
```